# XOR conditionally without branching if the lowest bit is set

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, branchless

I have three unsigned 32-bit integers, say `a`, `b`, and `c`. If the lowest bit of `b` is 1, I want to XOR `c` with `a`, and store the result into `c`. We can do this in the following way:

```
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
  // Some values for a and c
  unsigned a = 16;
  unsigned c = 25;

  unsigned b = 5; // 101_2

  if(b & 1)
  {
    c ^= a;
  }

  assert(c == 9);
}
```

Can I do this conditionally without branching, that is, with no if-statements?

Comment: With no `if` statements (and no ternary expression) it can be done easily. Without branching? That's harder. But first you should check if the code in your actual application really is a bottleneck, by measuring and profiling. Chances are the compiler might be able to optimize it anyway.

Comment: You should also consider the maintainability (and readability) of the code. Remember that you might have to maintain the code for quite some time, and by the time you come back to that specific parts of the code you will most likely forgotten what it does and more importantly *why* you do it that way. Having an `if` statement like you do in your example, that's very easy to understand what's happening. (though not the why).

Comment: You can but if you include a multiplication in the answer, it may take more clock cycles than the if statement.

Comment: @cup: it depends mostly on the pattern of values that `b&1` assumes; if it follows a predictable pattern the branch is substantially free, if it's almost random it can cost a lot - I'm currently working on a complex, CPU-bound algorithm, and about ~40% of the total running time is spent on a single unpredictable `je` instruction in the innermost loop, I'm sure that almost any branchless solution there could give substantial gains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `if` statement and without branching you have to check the assembly dump of your compiler:

```
c ^= ~((b & 1) - 1) & a;
```

Comment: @Gideon a trivial fix would have been then to replace `b` by `(b >> 31)` assuming `unsigned int` is 32-bit in your platform.

Answer (score 6):

There's lots of ways to do this.
Here's another, no multiply, only 4 operations.

```
c ^= a&(-(b&1));
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
c ^= a * ( b & 1 );
```